# Resume specific activity instead of launching new instance

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on a task switcher, and already figured out the way to show list of apps and switch to the app when user presses my notification. My problem is, instead of resuming the app, like launcher does, my app just starts new instance (resets) the activity it's switching to.

Here's the code I'm using to set the Intent:

```
ComponentName componentName = taskInfo.topActivity;
String packageName = componentName.getPackageName();

/*Setting intent*/
Intent startApp = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, startApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
childView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton2, pendingIntent);
```

To be clear, I want the user to be able to got back to whatever he was doing in that app instead of starting it anew.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?  I just asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222217/resume-singletask-activity

Comment: Partially; If I remember correctly PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag had to be removed since the "update" refers to intent rather than activity. Some users still reported thet this starts new activity for them.
I have since open-sourced the app, you can see the relevant part here: https://github.com/mick88/Alt-Tab/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mick88/alt/tab/TaskData.java#L30